# retrieve result from xmlHttpRequest

Tags: angular, typescript, xmlhttprequest

I had to convert a local audio for my angular project. The only way I found in order to do that is through XMLHttpRequest :

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();       
    xhr.open("GET", "/path/to/local/image/file", true); 
    xhr.responseType = "blob";
    xhr.onload = function (e) {
            console.log(this.response);
            var reader = new FileReader();
            reader.onload = function(event) {
               var res = event.target.result;
               console.log(res)
            }
            var file = this.response;
            reader.readAsDataURL(file)
    };
    xhr.send()
```

"res" is giving me the base64 for my audio. However I'm not able to retrieve res and store it in a variable to use it in another function.
How can I do that ? And is there a better way than going with XMLHttpRequest ?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd suggest you to use Angular HTTP Module. It's Angular native and as such easier to integrate with other parts of the application.

You could then use a container (like RxJS `ReplaySubject` with buffer 1) to cache/hold the values from the HTTP request and the subsequent `FileReader`'s `onload` callback.

Note: since this is all asynchronous, any statements that directly depend on the result from the HTTP request must be inside the subscription. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14220321/6513921) for more info on how async data works.

**app.module.ts**

```js
import { NgModule } from "@angular/core";
import { BrowserModule } from "@angular/platform-browser";
import { FormsModule } from "@angular/forms";
import { HttpClientModule } from "@angular/common/http";

import { AppComponent } from "./app.component";
import { DataService } from './data.service';

@NgModule({
  imports: [BrowserModule, FormsModule, HttpClientModule],
  declarations: [AppComponent],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent],
  providers: [DataService]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

**data.service.ts**

```js
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from "@angular/common/http";    // <-- import `HttpClient`

import { Observable, ReplaySubject } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable()
export class DataService {
  private fileSource: ReplaySubject<any> = new ReplaySubject<any>(1);
  public file$: Observable<any> = this.fileSource.asObservable();

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {             // <-- inject `HttpClient`
    this.getFile();                                   // <-- trigger file fetch here
  }

  getFile(): void {
    this.http.get('/path/to/local/image/file', { responseType: "blob" }).subscribe({    // <-- add `responseType`
      next: (response: any) => {
        const reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onload = (event) => {                  // <-- arrow function
           this.fileSource.next(event.target.result); // <-- push to the `ReplaySubject`
        }
        reader.readAsDataURL(response)                // <-- should NOT be `this.response`
      },
      error: (error: any) => {
        // handle error
      }
    });
  }
}
```

**app.component.ts**

```js
import { Component, OnInit, OnDestroy } from "@angular/core";

import { Subject } from "rxjs";
import { takeUntil } from "rxjs/operators";

import { DataService } from "./data.service";

@Component({ ... })
export class AppComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
  close$ = new Subject<any>();
  file: any;

  constructor(private _data: DataService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this._data.file$.pipe(
      takeUntil(this.close$)
    ).subscribe({
      next: (file: any) => {
        this.file = file;
        // other statements that depend on `this.file`
      }
    });
  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
    this.close$.next();           // <-- close open subscriptions
  }
}
```

### Update

- Add `responseType` to GET request
- Working example: [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-uxq4dh?file=src/app/data.service.ts)

Comment: Hello, thank you for your answer. However I'm not able to make it work and not getting any error. I looked with the debbuger : it's not entering the subscription

Comment: @yorozuya: There are two subscriptions. Which subscription does it not enter?

Comment: @yorozuya: Do you trigger the request in the service's constructor like shown? Also do you see the request executing without any errors in the browser's network page?

Comment: yes I do trigger it from the constructor and there is no errors

Comment: @yorozuya: One error I could see is this line: `reader.readAsDataURL(this.response)`. It should be `reader.readAsDataURL(response)`. I've updated the code. Please see it works now. In any case the subscription's `next` callback should be triggered if there are no errors in the request.

Comment: @yorozuya: The `responseType: 'blob'` need to added for blob files in the GET request. The default is `json`. I've updated the answer and included a working example.

Comment: Thank you so so much Michael, it's working and you explained very well !